# PostgreSQL: aggregate expression on a subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

A total beginner's question: I wanted to run a sub-query with GROUP BY statement, and then find out a row with maximum value in the result. I have built an expression like that below:

```
SELECT agg.facid, agg.Slots
FROM
(SELECT facid AS facid, SUM(slots) AS Slots FROM cd.bookings
GROUP BY facid
ORDER BY SUM(slots) DESC) AS agg
WHERE agg.Slots = (SELECT MAX(Slots) FROM agg);
```

In my mind, this should first create a 2-column table with facid and SUM(slots) values, and then by addressing these columns as agg.facid and agg.Slots I should get only the row with max value in "Slots". However, instead I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "agg" does not exist
LINE 6: WHERE agg.Slots = (SELECT MAX(Slots) FROM agg);
```

This is probably something very simple, so I am sorry in advance for a silly problem ;)

I am working on PostgreSQL 10, with pgAdmin 4.

Comment: Check out the HAVING clause, should be able to do it without a subquery even.

Comment: If I using HAVING statement like so, I still get an error:SELECT agg.facid, agg.Slots
FROM
(SELECT facid AS facid, SUM(slots) AS Slots FROM cd.bookings
GROUP BY facid
HAVING Slots = MAX(Slots)) AS agg; ERROR:  column "bookings.slots" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Common Table Expression:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

```
WITH agg AS (
    SELECT facid AS facid, SUM(slots) AS Slots 
    FROM cd.bookings
    GROUP BY facid
    )
SELECT agg.facid, agg.Slots
FROM agg
WHERE agg.Slots = (SELECT MAX(Slots) FROM agg);
```

Comment: Ah, noticed your answer after the web page refreshed upon posting an answer to my own question ;) Thanks for your feedback mate!

Answer (score 1):

So a bit more of a research, and I figured a solution which might be clean enough to my liking, using a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH sum AS (SELECT facid, SUM(slots) AS Slots FROM cd.bookings GROUP BY facid)
SELECT facid, Slots
FROM sum
WHERE Slots = (SELECT MAX(Slots) FROM sum);
```

The first line declares a CTE, which can later be called for a sub-query calculating what is the max value in aggregated slots column.
Hope it helps anyone interested.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you are looking for?

```
SELECT
    facid,
    SUM(slots)
FROM cd.bookings
GROUP BY
    facid
HAVING SUM(slots) = MAX(slots)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work mate, because that MAX(slots) function just picks a max value in a single slots cell, before summing them up by facid.